# UWP Sqlite one-to-many relation

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to use SQLite with the new `EF Core` and have been following the [tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html). Before I used SQLite too, but I used an extra DB-class with references to the real class. e.g. below `Blog_DB` contains the `ID` to the `BlogImage` (another class) and then I used to create the real `Blog` class, that loads the `BlogImage` class into `Blog.BlogImage`.

```
public class Blog_DB
{
public int BlogId { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }

public int BlogImageID { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
public int BlogId { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }

public BlogImage BlogImage { get; set; }
}

public class BlogImage
{
    public int BlogImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

However now I heard about EF Core and it's `one-to-one` and `one-to-many` relation, which is done the following way:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public BlogImage BlogImage { get; set; }
}

public class BlogImage
{
    public int BlogImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

But I do not understand, how this works (or I did not understand/read the documentation right) as when I load `Blogs` the Entry `BlogImage` is empty.

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var m = db.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(); // the first entry
    m.BlogImage = new BlogImage { Caption = "My Caption" }; // does not work
    db.BlogImage.Add(new BlogImage { Blog = m, BlogId = m.BlogId, Caption = "My Caption" }); // doesn't work either
    db.SaveChanges();                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I load Blogs the Entry BlogImage is empty.

In Entity Framework, an entity can be related to other entities through an association (relationship). And the [Navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/data/jj713564.aspx) provide a way to navigate an association between two entity types, and loading the related Navigation properties is achieved by use of the **Include** method. As the official document for EF Core is not complete, here is the documentation about [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232) for EF6.x.

In this case, entity BlogImage is a **navigation property** for entity Blog. So using `db.BlogImage.Add(new BlogImage { Blog = m, BlogId = m.BlogId, Caption = "My Caption" });` to add BlogImage does work, but you should use **Include** method to load entity BlogImage for Blog.

Following is the code I have verified:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    // load the Blog without BlogImage
    var blogWithoutBlogImage = db.Blogs.FirstOrDefault();//blogWithoutBlogImage.BlogImage is null

    // load the Blog inclue the BlogImage
    var blogWithBlogImage = db.Blogs.Include(x => x.BlogImage).FirstOrDefault();
    var blogImage = blogWithBlogImage.BlogImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly, what I was looking for, the `Include` part did the trick